# How to show self-hosted tiles using deck.gl MVtLayer?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, deck.gl

This may be in the series of dumb questions, but when I look at https://deck.gl/docs/api-reference/geo-layers/mvt-layer, I do not understand how to make a MVTLayer that fetches self-hosted tiles without React pieces. Can someone help? This would feel to be even large interest now that buildless is also becoming a thing in web programming.

What I would like to achieve is a simple HTML (e.g. index.html) file that uses a script tag like `<script src="https://unpkg.com/deck.gl@8.4.5/dist.min.js"></script>` and the example from the aforementioned Deck.gl that looks like (I changed the URL)

```
import DeckGL from '@deck.gl/react';
import {MVTLayer} from '@deck.gl/geo-layers';

function App({viewState}) {
  const layer = new MVTLayer({
    data: `https://<selfhostedurl>/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf`,

    minZoom: 0,
    maxZoom: 23,
    getLineColor: [192, 192, 192],
    getFillColor: [140, 170, 180],

    getLineWidth: f => {
      switch (f.properties.class) {
        case 'street':
          return 6;
        case 'motorway':
          return 10;
        default:
          return 1;
      }
    },
    lineWidthMinPixels: 1
  });

  return <DeckGL viewState={viewState} layers={[layer]} />;
}
```

but instead make this a without React. I see it requires a bit more code on how to define a canvas HTML element and use it. Maplibre example would be OK too. :) There is one Maplibre example at https://codepen.io/snickell/pen/dypOWzj.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Scripting API](https://deck.gl/docs/get-started/using-standalone#using-the-scripting-api) for more 'simple' examples, [here](https://codepen.io/AdriSolid/pen/dyORrbg) you have an example of using `MVTLayer`.

**Deck.gl offers a standalone bundled version of the library - a native JavaScript scripting interface like that of d3.js.**

As simple as

```
const deckgl = new deck.DeckGL({
  container: 'map',
  mapStyle: 'https://maps-api-v2.us.carto.com/user/public/carto/sql/{z}/{x}/{y}?source=SELECT * FROM ne_10m_railroads_public&api_key=default_public&format=mvt',
  initialViewState: {
    latitude: 41.4,
    longitude: 2.18,
    zoom: 5,
  },
  controller: true,
  layers: [
    new deck.MVTLayer({
      data: 'https://d25uarhxywzl1j.cloudfront.net/v0.1/{z}/{x}/{y}.mvt',
      getLineColor: [192, 192, 192],
      lineWidthMinPixels: 1
    })
  ]
});
```